# Can a message be passed with abstract method or interface?

Tags: java, comments, abstract-class, abstraction

Is there any way in which we can pass a message with **abstract** method or any **interface** method, so when somebody implements my abstract method they can get message I passed.
I tried with **Comment, Java-Doc, TODO** but nothing shows when I implement abstract method in different class, so is there a way that while implementing my abstract method either comment, Javadoc, TODO also implemented

**Abstractdemo.java**

```
int x;
int y;
int sum;

public abstract void add(); 
    // use this to implement addition of two number
    // or
    // TODO use this to implement addition of two number
}
```

**Calculator.java**

```
public class Calculator extends Abstractdemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    @Override
    public void add() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Instead of `Auto generated stub` I want my TODO or comment to show

Comment: I'm not sure I quite get it but putting a JavaDoc on the abstract method and none on the override your IDE should then display the abstract method's JavaDoc. Besides that comments and TODOs (which are just comments) aren't in any way related to a method at least not in the way you've used them. The IDE won't know that those are intended to be the method's "default" body.

Comment: @Thomas  Yes, you are right that IDE does not know if Comments are specific to that method or not and that's what I am asking is there any way to display message when implementing abstract method or way of giving hint  and Yes I also tried java doc method It didn't work

Comment: Well generally I'd try to make the method signature itself as descriptive as possible and add any additional information in a JavaDoc (which of course isn't _copied_ to the implementation but displayed _instead_ of the implementation's JavaDoc if there isn't any yet).

Comment: @Thomas  Yes that's what you should do but I want to know if it is possible

Comment: Well it _might_ be possible depending on the IDE (you might need to add a custom plugin or write something yourself) but since you probably wouldn't want to force the use of any IDE I'd just not bother with that and use the sensible approach right away.

Comment: @Thomas  Yes that's No No option, Using Custom plugin is futile approach, It will be more benefiting to implement some native solution, So it does force to choose IDE

Comment: Well, any code generation is already done by the IDE so there will be no "native" support for any of this (the JDK doesn't provide a "generate implementations" functionality - those are all provided by 3rd party libraries/IDEs).

Comment: @Thomas   /**@Inheritdoc**/ is way to inherit doc but user have to do it explicitly there is no way to provide default implementation.

Comment: Well, there _is_ a way to provide that default JavaDoc for generated methods in Eclipse (would probably be for all though). However, at least Eclipse does display the "super JavaDoc" anyway if there's no more specialized one. - And you or another Dev might not even be using Eclipse.